# "You are not authorized to view this page" error message in Chrome only

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection

All of a sudden when I try to open SSRN papers (like http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2270973) I receive the following message in Chrome:

[image]

It is only in Chrome and when I use a different computer with the same router (also with Chrome) it opens just fine. So it cannot be the IP address either that is blocked.

When can I do?

**EDIT**
I just found out that it works in incognito mode. This is getting stranger...

Comment: Did you try clearing your cookies and cache? [Here's a guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582) in case you don't know now to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need to clear your cookies.  Click on the triple bar on the upper right of chrome, select settings, then click on show advanced settings, then click clear browsing data.  I would start off with just deleting the cookies and see if that fixes the issue.